# Arduino tutorial: compile error in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, rosserial, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on the rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello World tutorial and when I compile the example code I get this error message:

In file included from /home/ryan/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38:0,
from HelloWorld.cpp:6:
/home/ryan/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:39:38: fatal error: rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I've tried copying and pasting files and folders with no luck.
I'm thinking maybe Arduino can't find my ros_workspace folder?

UPDATE: I repeated the tutorial and discovered that rosmake fails after the command: rosmake rosserial_arduino. The rosmake summary reads like this:
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosserial_arduino written to:
[ rosmake ] /home/ryan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120514-181947/rosserial_arduino/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosserial_arduino [FAIL] [ 6.52 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosserial_arduino.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. [ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 17 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/ryan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120514-181947

What would cause rosmake to fail?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33977/arduino-tutorial:-compile-error-in-arduino-ide/) by [RyanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/1969/ryang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-14**:
More information is needed to figure that out. Could you paste the output of "roscd rosserial_arduino && make"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working with ROS on Arduino requires copying files into your Arduino sketchbook. Be sure you have copied ros_lib from the ROS environment to your sketchbook. The beginning of the arduino tutorials provide instructions/commands for doing so.

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-06-06**:
I have the same issue in groovy. I have copied this files roslib in my sketchbook/libraries folder but that doesn't solve the problem. There is no node_handle.h in the folder.

**Comment by [zapk](https://answers.ros.org/users/15421/zapk/) on 2014-05-01**:
Hi, I have the same problem in 2014 with Hydro :( Anybody found the solution?

**Comment by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on 2015-01-21**:
Hey I have the same problem in 2015 with Hydro...